# what is the significance of tulsi at homes?

Tags: rituals, other-religions, science, tulasi

I have seen Every Hindu having a Tulsi plant at home and being worshipped everyday....In Modern days as today why would one need a Tulsi Plant at home?
Is it useful or just because of rituals
Why do hindus plant a tulsi tree outside their homes?
Any scientific reasons?

Comment: In modern days we need it even more coz most people that we see around us are diseased to start with. Apart from being worthy of worship this plant have many healing properties too.